# Showing Progresscircle in Asynctask

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, progress-bar

I want to show an progresscircle while a chat is loading. So I put some progressbar in, visibility set to invisible. Now I set in `onPreExecute()` the visibility to visible and in `onPostExecute()` to invisible. 
The circle is shown, but just when the chat already did load AND it doesnt disappear. Can someone tell me my mistake? :o

```
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        MainActivity.pbReadChat.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, ArrayList<String>> doInBackground(String... strings) {
       //...
    return result;
}

public void onPostExecute(Map<String, ArrayList<String>> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    MainActivity.pbReadChat.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Edit: Now it disappears but it gets just shown after chat already did load in `doInBackground()`

That are the important things of my Async class I think, hope someone can help me

Comment: My guess is that your onPostExecute() never gets called. You can check by inserting a breakpoint. Code in your doInBackground() could shed more light on the problem.

Comment: why does it not get called? I thought an Async does these 3 steps: onpreexecute, doinbackground and onpostexecute... and why does the circle just appear when doinbackground finished?

Comment: onPostExecute() is called when doInBackground returns. If it doesn't (because of infinite loop or exception, or task being cancelled), onPostExecute() is not called.

Comment: ah okay, now it disappears right, but the circle doesnt appears on beginning, it first does doinbackground, then shows the circle a very little moment and then hide it in onpostexecute :o

Comment: Hmm... there's no obvious reason for that. Do you override onPreExecute() correctly? You could have hidden or overloaded it by accident.

Comment: found the reason, the execute with .get(); freezes the gui, I will need another way (: thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onPostExecute()` is not being called because `doInBackground()` does not return. It can happen because of one of the reasons below:

1. Infinite loop.
2. Infinite wait for an input.
3. Unchecked exception.
4. `cancel()` being called on `AsyncTask`. In this case, `onCancelled()` is called instead of `onPostExecute()`